# Playing custom sounds for flutter_local_notification

Tags: flutter, push-notification, flutter-dependencies, flutter-local-notification

I need to play a custom alert for push notifications and I'm using [flutter_local_notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications). I have added an audio file in android/app/src/main/res/raw/ and also enabled playSound to true, but it still plays the default sound. Is there anything I missed?

```
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel_id',
      'channel_name',
      enableLights: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound("notification"),
      playSound: true,
```

[image]